# Widgets- Icons too small

Tags: product-images, widgets

When I try including widgets the product images are barely visible. (Too small)  Is there anyway to rectify this?

Comment: Please always mention the Magento version for which you are asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

- Log in to your Magento admin panel.
- Navigate to "Content" and select "Widgets" from the dropdown menu.
- Locate the widget you are using and click on its "Edit" button.
- Look for the image size options within the widget configuration, such as "Image Width" and "Image Height".
- Increase the dimensions or specify custom sizes according to your
  preference.
- Save the widget settings and test the widget on the frontend to see
  the updated image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

The product images are appearing too small when including widgets in Magento, you can try adjusting the settings or implementing a solution to rectify this issue. Here are a few steps you can take to resolve the problem

1.Check widget configuration: Review the configuration of the widget you are using to ensure that the image size settings are appropriate

2.Theme settings: Check your Magento theme settings to see if there are any specific image size settings that might be affecting the widget display

3.CSS modifications: If the widget's appearance is controlled by CSS, you can modify the CSS rules to increase the image size

4.Customization: If the above options do not work, you might need to customize the widget code. You can locate the widget code files in the Magento file structure and make modifications to the image size parameters directly

5.Magento extensions: There might be Magento extensions available specifically designed to enhance image display or provide additional customization options

NOTE:Remember to clear your Magento cache and refresh the page after making any changes to see the updated widget display.